# C# foreach interrompido

Tags: c#, foreach

Quando tento mover os controlos de um `FlowLayouPanel` para outro `flpPropriedades -> flpReserva` através de um loop `foreach` ele sai a meio e não completa a transição.

```
foreach (Control control in flpPropriedade.Controls)   
{             
   flpReserva.Controls.Add(control);   
}

flpReserva.Refresh();
flpPropriedade.Refresh();
```

O que poderia causar a saída inesperado do loop?

Comment: Isso deve estar acontecendo quando você faz o Refresh dentro do foreach sendo que seu controle flpPropriedade está em uso pelo loop.

Comment: Eu não faço o refresh dentro do foreach

Comment: Eu não faço o refresh dentro do foreach

Answer (score 0):

A solução encontrada foi fazer um ciclo `do...While`:

```
do
{
    flpReserva.Controls.Add(flpPropriedade.Controls[0]);
}
while (flpPropriedade.Controls.Count != 0);
```

Comment: Sua resposta ficou bem incompleta. Cadê o restante do código da pergunta? flpReserva use {   }  para delimitar a parte do seu código para ter um visual mais intuitivo.